# How do I explain to my MSI BIOS that I don't have a PUMP Fan anymore and that's OK?

Tags: bios, water-cooling

I bought an MSI prebuild PC with a [MPG Z590M GAMING EDGE WIFI](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-Z590M-GAMING-EDGE-WIFI) mainboard and CPU water cooling which I assume is a [MAG CORELIQUID 120R](https://www.msi.com/Liquid-Cooling/MAG-CORELIQUID-120R).

The water cooling had some issues (don't ask), so I replaced it with a regular air cooler. I connected that new cooler fan to the "CPU_FAN1" connector on the mainboard. The "PUMP_FAN1" connector which was previously used by the water cooler is now unused.

The system runs perfectly fine now, even under continuous heavy CPU load.

However, every time I start the PC, the BIOS greets me with a red warning text saying "Pump fan error, Please check". I would like that warning to go away.

I already tried these things in the BIOS settings:

- "CPU Cooler Tuning": Switched from "Water Cooler" to "Tower Air Cooler" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liz4n.png)). This didn't do anything.
- Switched the "CPU Fan Fail Warning Control" toggle off ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dqwz.png)). That did the trick, but I don't feel very comfortable disabling that setting, because I assume it will then no longer warn me if my new CPU fan fails for whatever reason.

Is there a way to stop my BIOS from complaining about the missing PUMP fan without also disabling warnings about any other fans?

Comment: try boxed cooler. my rudimentary understanding is tower and water are the same. they deliver more power then boxed so im going to guess thats through using both the Pump fan header  and cpu1

Comment: @cubesareneat boxed and tower coolers really just differ by their mechanical design. The major difference between water cooling and air cooling is that water cooling requires not one but two independent power connections. One for the pump which circulates the coolant between CPU and radiator and one for the fan(s) which cool(s) the radiator.